# Python - Selenium webdriver method .get returns 'None' for any url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a script for scraping some websites. However, I am unable to move past the very first step, since .get method returns 'None' value for any website I try.

This is how my code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

s=Service('D:/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)
print(driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/about_careers.htm/"))
driver.quit()
```

Here's what I have already tried:

1. Made sure the latest version of Selenium is installed;
2. Made sure that my chromedriver's version is the same as Chrome's -- both are 107;
3. Added the services bit, as before adding that, I would get an error saying: 'DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object';
4. Tried to move chromedriver.exe to Chrome/Applicatiom folder and even my project folder, both did not work.

NB, the above website is just some random example, I've tried many websites and all of them return 'None'. Also, I cannot use bs4 for the websites I want to scrape, so that is not an option.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: `driver.get()` does not actually return anything.  What were you expecting to be returned?  If you want to access the html source, that will be in the `driver.page_source` attribute after performing a `get()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. My brain must not be working today. Thank you!!!

Comment: @JohnGordon it probably will be better if you write the above comment as an answer so this question with it answer will be more accessible for future users